# Track what zsh-plugins create .zcompdump file under homeuser

Tags: zsh

I have this line in `.zshrc` that instructs zsh to create `.zcompdump` file under `~/.cache/zsh/` but I believe a zsh plugin created it somehow under homeuser:

`autoload -Uz compinit                                                                                                   compinit -d ~/.cache/zsh/zcompdump-$ZSH_VERSION`

How to know what plugin created `zcompdump` and how to completely redirect it to `~/.cache/zsh/`?

EDIT: from `zsh-x` I can see these suspicious lines:

```
+/home/user/.zsh/scripts/SCRIPT.zsh:11> compinit
+compinit:70> emulate -L zsh
+compinit:71> setopt extendedglob
+compinit:73> typeset _i_dumpfile _i_files _i_line _i_done _i_dir _i_autodump=1
+compinit:74> typeset _i_tag _i_file _i_addfiles _i_fail=ask _i_check=yes _i_name
+compinit:76> [[ 0 -gt 0 ]]
+compinit:108> typeset -gHA _comps _services _patcomps _postpatcomps
+compinit:113> typeset -gHA _compautos
+compinit:118> typeset -gHA _lastcomp
+compinit:121> [[ -n '' ]]
+compinit:125> typeset -g _comp_dumpfile=/home/user/.zcompdump
```

Does this mean `SCRIPT.zsh` create `.zcompdump` file?

Comment: Try `zsh -x` to see what calls `compinit`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I've just updated the details.

Comment: Sounds like you have your culprit.

Comment: I see, just modify its `compinit` and all is good. Thanks.